# Difference between an Entity and a Relation

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I am currently reading about entities and relations and I can't understand the difference between them? According to Wikipedia we have an example of a relation like in the pic:

[image: relation]

This looks exactly like an entity set. What's the difference between an entity and a relation?

Comment: Maybe you mean, entity vs relationship? As in ER modeling? Both have associated relations/tables, types/classes and sets (of instances).

Answer (score 7):

"Entity" is a real world concept, such as "a person" in your example.

"Relation" is a set of tuples (records), each representing a model of an entity. In your example each tuple represents attributes of a single person, and their collection is a relation.

Comment: I would also add that a Relation has a header.

Answer (score 0):

#### Entity == A Row of table == Tuple == Record

Entity:

1. An entity is a thing or an object in the real world that is distinguishable from other objects based on the values of the attributes it possess.
2. Entity can not be represented in ER diagram as it is an instance/data.
3. Entity can be represented in a Relational model by row/tuple/record.

---

#### Relation == Entity Set == Table

Entity Set:

1. Collection/Set of same types of entities. i.e. that share same properties or attributes is called entity set.
2. Entity Set is represented by rectangle in ER diagram.
3. Entity Set is represented by table in relational model.

Answer (score -1):

"She is my mother."

"She" and the implied "you" are the entities. "Mother" is the relationship.

"Sally Smith is my mother."

"Sally Smith" is a particular entity (a row in a table).

Or: how does this thing relate to that thing?

Comment: The question seems to be about relations, not relationships.

Answer (score -4):

Relation is an instance ( a record) of an entity